The probability of that n-th random variable is not equal to the previous $n-1$-variables
I am working on a probability problem involving a sequence of independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables  $X_1, X_2, \cdots$, each taking values in the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.
Define  $q_n$  as the probability that the  $n$-th random variable  $X_n$  takes a value different from all of the previous  $n-1$  variables, i.e.,
$$
q_n = \mathbb{P}(X_n \notin \{X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{n-1}\}).
$$
I would like to prove that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} q_n = 0.
$$
I would appreciate any suggestions, hints, or references to similar results that might help with this proof. Thank you in advance!

For each $k\in \mathbb N$, let $p_k=P(X_1=k)$. Given $\newcommand{\e}{\varepsilon}\e>0$, we must show that $q_n<\e$ when $n$ is sufficiently large. To this end, let $M$ be a large enough natural number such that $P(X_1>M)<\e/2$.
$$
\begin{align}
q_n
&= \sum_{k\in \mathbb N}P\left(X_n=k\;\text{ and }\;\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}\{X_{i}\neq k\}\right)
\\
&= \sum_{k\in \mathbb N} p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}
\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^M p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}+\sum_{k=M+1}^\infty p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}
\\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^M p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}+\sum_{k=M+1}^\infty p_k
\\
&\le  \sum_{k=1}^M p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}+P(X_1>M)
\\
&\le  \sum_{k=1}^M p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}+\e/2.
\end{align}
$$
Each $p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so $\sum_{k=1}^M p_k(1-p_k)^{n-1}$ is at most $\e/2$ for large enough $n$. Therefore, we have shown $q_n<\e/2+\e/2=\e$,  completing the proof that $\lim_n q_n=0$.

Hint: try to develop a recursive dependence between $q_{n+1}$ and $q_n$. That is, describe as two events
$$X_{n+1}\notin \{X_1\ldots X_n\} \Leftrightarrow X_{n+1}\neq X_n\textrm{ and } X_{n+1}\notin \{X_1\ldots X_{n-1}\}$$
so that the second event has probability just $q_n$. The first event is independent and its probability is easy to calculate as $$p=\sum_i p_i \bar p_i$$ where $p_i$ is the probability for $i$ to occur in a particular roll. So $p$ is a constant, easily shown to be strictly less than 1, and $q_n$ is a geometric progression.
